# Create bin for a variable with same number of records in Tableau

Tags: grouping, tableau-api

I need to create groups for one variable that has the same number of records, instead of the same "size".

For example, I have 10,000 records of cars with prices between $5,000 and $10,000. Instead of a classical bin with a range size $1,000 each and unequal number of records, I want bins that has exactly the same number of records, even if the price range in unequal.

**Classic Bin**

[image: Classical bin]

**Desired Bit**

[image: The bin I want]

Is this possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableau doesn't allow different sized bins.
Try making the bins using # of Records (2000 in this case, or Tableau suggested).
Then create some table calculations for Min and Max price fixed with each bin to get the range.

Comment: You are right, apparently it can't be done. Thank you.